# Microsoft Project Server 2010 reject task changes like finish date

Tags: resources, ms-project-server-2010

I have create a pwa in project server 2010. 
Then I create new project, defining tasks and assigning those tasks to resources.
I have set time reporting period so any resource must report her/his working time about any task assigned to her/him.

When a resource changes any field of his/her tasks (e.g. Finish Date, Remaining Work, %Work, ...) he/she Send status to PM for approval.

When PM rejects this page and publish project again, this change does not take effect in resource's timesheet. But since this changes rejected, one reasonably can expect that in the case of rejection, the changes come back to old.

Is anyone know how can resource bring out that fields to their old values?
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is rather based on my knowledge of how MSP database looks like than on my experience in similar cases.

MSP does not store any kind of "transactional" data. You cannot do some changes in a project plan and later reject them and rollback all the changes to some previous state. Draft database stores current status of a project, Published database stores the last snapshot of the project created during publishing procedure. The only database which can store several versions of the same project is Archive.

So practically the only way to "rollback" some changes in a project is to put the project into  Archive before somebody change it and restore it from the Archive when it was decided that the changes should be rejected.

Comment: Thanks melan. I think you're right. But this method is very time consuming and reduce performance. I am already searching for a better way to roll back the rejected changes.